# How do you take a SQlite result and insert it into Model Values so they can be reused?

Tags: c#, sqlite, maui

Details in the title, code is below. How do I populate the model values from the SQlite response?

```
//Current line returns the below response
var test2 = await Database.QueryAsync<User>("SELECT * FROM User");
```

[Return result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lSDxA.png)

Model

```
    public class User
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }
        public string Username { get; set; }
        public string Token { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: I don't know what library you are using so I don't know how it works, but the code implies that `test2` will already be a `User` instance. What library is `Database.QueryAsync` from?

Comment: Thank you for the Help, I apologize I'm still getting used to C#, the library is 
            "Database = new SQLiteAsyncConnection(Constants.DatabasePath, Constants.Flags);"

Comment: This is what I just tried, "var test2 = await Database.QueryAsync<User>("SELECT * FROM User");
            var test3 = test2.Cast<User>().ToArray();
            User = test3[0];" it is seems to pupulate the User fields base on the return object but when I try to call "User" somewhere else in the code it gets reported as null

Comment: I see. You named the connection "Database". A little misleading. Anyway, your problem is elsewhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SQLite.NET will return a list of `User` objects, you don't need to do anything to populate them

```
var query = await Database.Table<User>();
var results = await query.ToListAsync();

foreach (var user in results)
{
   // user is a User object
}
```

Comment: Thank you, that helped shorten my code down tremendously. I did as you mentioned and utilized your code snippet. `var query = Database.Table<User>();
            var results = await query.ToListAsync();
            foreach (var user in results)
            {
                User = user;
            }` But when I try to pull the User model in another part of my code it gets returned as null, would it be how I have the code structured for the model? `if User != null)
        {
            App.Current.MainPage = new Shell();
        } `

Comment: I can only comment on code I can see.  I have no idea what is happening elsewhere in your code

Comment: Fair point, thank you for the help Jason.